# How to write sql query to find the output below?

Tags: sql, formatting

I have data in my table as below

| cust_id | dates | attendance_ind |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-01-15 | 1 |
| A | 2022-02-15 | 1 |
| A | 2022-03-15 | 0 |
| A | 2022-04-15 | 1 |
| A | 2022-05-15 | 0 |
| B | 2022-01-15 | 0 |
| B | 2022-02-15 | 1 |
| B | 2022-03-15 | 1 |
| B | 2022-04-15 | 1 |

desired output:

| cust_id | date | date range |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | jan-15 | jan-15 to feb-15 |
| A | apr-15 | apr-15 to apr-15 |
| B | feb-15 | feb-15 to apr-15 |

I am unable to solve it, need help.

Comment: which DBMS is this ? mysql ?

Comment: its an interview question and i am testing it on snowflake

Answer (score 2):

You can get result with something like this:

```sql
with dates_segments as(
    select *,
        sum(1-attendance_ind) over (partition by cust_id order by dates) segment
    from test_variants tv
),
  numerated_dates_segments as (
    select *,
        row_number() Over (PARTITION BY cust_id, segment order by dates) dates_asc,
        row_number() Over (PARTITION BY cust_id, segment order by dates desc) dates_desc
    from dates_segments 
    where attendance_ind <> 0
)
select nds_asc.cust_id, nds_asc.dates, nds_desc.dates 
  from numerated_dates_segments nds_asc
  join numerated_dates_segments nds_desc 
    on (nds_asc.cust_id = nds_desc.cust_id
        and nds_asc.segment = nds_desc.segment
        and nds_desc.dates_desc = 1)
 where nds_asc.dates_asc = 1
```

Here:

- CTE `dates_segments` splits rows in sequential date blocks,
- CTE `numerated_dates_segments` numerates dates present in blocks in both directions,
- main query joins `numerated_dates_segments` with itself, to get first and last date of block.

*Caution:* this query assumes rows are sequential based on order of dates, and doesn't check if there are duplicates, and if timespan between rows makes any sense (it doesn't care 1 month or 11 years)

Example at [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QNu1tLzG).